# Responsive cross browser solution for equal height columns with children

Tags: css, height

Straight to the point.

I need a solution for a responsive two column component layout like on the picture bellow.

[image]

The `.left` / `.right` column width ratio should always be 75 / 25% of `.parent` and their heights should always be in sync.

The `.left` column should contain an image which scales in width and height with every viewport change and the `.right` column should contain three child elements (`.cta`) which take exactly 1/3 each of `.parent` height.

The criteria for an acceptable solution are:

- support for as many devices and browsers as possible (IE9+ is fine)
- support for vendor specific browsers which brands like HTC like to use etc.
- flexbox is not an option
- although it would be trivial to use JavaScript to set an explicit height for both `.left` and `.right` I'd like to come up with a non-JS solution

The closest I've come up to a satisfying solution is using `display: table-cell;` to make sure `.left` and `.right` heights are always synced. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work in IE because of the the CSS specifications which clearly state that if both parent and child containers use percentages to define their dimensions and they depend on each other's flows to calculate those dimensions the outcome is undefined. That affects the `.right` container height which expands to full height in every browser except IE.

[**Codepen example**](http://codepen.io/holodoc/pen/beqVdY?editors=1100)

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="image-container"><img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/1300x780" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="cta">
      <a>LINK #1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="cta">
      <a>LINK #2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="cta">
      <a>LINK #3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent > div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  width: 75%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  background: #bbb;
}

.cta {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #bbb;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.cta a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

If everything fails there is always JavaScript as a backup solution. But it bogs my mind that in 2016. we are still cursed to deal with hacks to achieve such simple solutions like the one I need.

Comment: Why is flexbox not an option? You are complaining about there not being simple solutions, but you just excluded the most simple one.

Comment: @MitchelJager Because flexbox is not supported by devices which still use the stock Android browser (at least not in the standard way), most notably the whole HTC line of devices, and it's buggy and unpredictable in IE. Therefore, it's not an option in this case.

Comment: I'm a fan of flexbox, but you make a fair point.

Comment: To counter your point, on mobile devices you generally have everything in a single column, removing the need for flexbox. Although I do suppose that is not necessarily true for tablets. You could also simply use a polyfill,

Comment: @MitchelJager Its not uncommon to have a multiple column block grid type of layout on mobile devices where flexbox is not just used for managing horizontal but also vertical space (equal heights etc.) Having to deal with different code that will accommodate the needs of different devices kind of defeats the purpose of flexbox in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If crossbrowser but not for dinosaurs thne `inline-block` and a pinch of `calc()` might help:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
}
.parent div div a,
.parent div  div {
  border: solid 1px;
}
.parent div.left {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid 1px;
}
.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
.parent {
  width: 70%;/* demo purpose, do run it in full page too */
  margin: auto;
  background:yellow;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.parent .left {
  width: 75%;
}
.parent .right {
  width: 25%;
}
.parent div div a {
  margin: 0.88em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  /* if floatting pseudo do
  overflow:hidden;*/
}
.parent div div a:before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: calc(60% - 0.5em);/* is calc() allowed ?  if not keep 60% and remove margin:1em from links */
  /* float:left; or with vertical-align */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/1300x780" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div><!-- cure white-space disturbance
  --><div class="right">
    <div class="cta">
      <a>LINK #1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="cta">
      <a>LINK #2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="cta">
      <a>LINK #3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjpdZE

IE11 gets it : [image: ie11 screen]

Comment: Unfortunately this solution suffers from the same problem - the height of the `.right` container doesn't expand to the height of the `.parent` container in any IE.

Comment: @holodoc what kind of IE are you running ? cause, besides calc() most of them understands vertical padding in **%** and inline-block (IE6 might be out ) but the rest , you surprise me :) i updated snippet with borders and background to parent .parent, also linked a codepen

Comment: I've run the code through several local machines running IE9, IE10 and IE11 and then tried the same on several browserstack.com machines. All came up with a negative result. However, the codepen you posted works which is weird. I will have to take a closer look at the code. I won't mark your post as an answer yet just to see if anyone else might contribute. Other than that a big thanks for your input.

Comment: @holodoc strange, i'm curious, does your own test is on line , i would like to see my IE11 behavior and hopefully see where or why it breaks :)

Comment: I really like the idea behind this solution however I've decided to use JavaScript here for one simple reason - inconsistency in how browsers round percentage math which often causes a difference of 1-2px between `.right` and `.left` heights. If there wasn't a requirement to make the layout pixel perfect because of the backgrounds I would use this approach without even giving it a second thought. Thanks again!

Comment: @holodoc looks also to me like a typical and wise use of javascript here :).